# layout_anchor between toolbar and layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a view to be anchored between AppBarLayout and layout. I get this behavior only on Android Studio editor, but on real device is different like so:
[image]

I am really confused. My code is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="view.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

      <!--views on toolbar-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/activity_home_content" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_accent"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/whole_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start">

    <!--img view-->
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and '**activity_home_content**'

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/whole_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="view.activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_toolbar">


<!--some other views-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think changing the elevation of "AvatarView" to more than that of AppBarLayout should work

Comment: @AjilO. what do you mean by _changing the elevation_ ? I put `app:layout_anchor="@+id/whole_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"` to achieve desired behavior

Comment: True. But `whole_layout` would be placed below `AppBarLayout`. I didn't confirm; but I believe `AppBarLayout` has an elevation of 8dp by default. Where as your LinearLayout (`whole_layout`) would be at 0dp elevation. And the `RelativeView` you are trying to anchor also gets it's elevation as 0dp by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried it. As I mentioned in the comments, your `whole_layout` is a `LinearLayout` with elevation 0dp. Any element you anchor to this `LinearLayout` will receive an elevation of 0dp (same as the view you are anchoring to) by default. This means that the `RelativeLayout` will have an elevation of 0dp.

The `AppBarLayout` has an elevation of 4dp, so by default the `RelativeLayout` will always be drawn below it.

**The Fix**

Give an elevation to the relative layout that is greater than or equal to 4. This will fix your problem, except that the `RelativeLayout` will now cast a shadow too.

Here is the code for the `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_accent"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/whole_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <!--img view-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still not working for me. After I scroll it to top it goes below app bar